# In the context of memory hierarchy, why there is "write miss policy", but no "read miss policy"?

Tags: caching, memory, mips, hierarchy

I suspect since write-miss is more complicated than read-miss, we need some kind of policy to be able to execute it properly and also to further optimize it. However, I am not sure about the exact answer and there isn't any further explanation on the book either. Further explanation is very much appreciated, thank you

Comment: "Write miss policy" and "read miss policy" aren't commonly used terms, so it is unclear what you are even asking. Do you mean write policy and read policy? Please clarify the question.

Comment: @ihonen what I meant by writing miss policy is that when you wanted to write to the cache and the requested block is not there, the well-known examples for write miss policy are write-through and write-back

Comment: You are confusing cache miss handling with write policy. Whenever a cache miss occurs, the requested data is fetched from lower levels of the memory hierarchy, and the way this is done is essentially the same for both reads and writes. Write policy is in no way connected to cache misses - it only specifies when changes made to cached data are propagated down the memory hierarchy, i.e. at which point the changes will show up in RAM and not just the cache (to simplify things a bit).

Comment: @ihonen wow okay, that makes things clear, thank you very much

Comment: Happy to help. :) If you wish to learn more about the details of caching, [part 2](https://lwn.net/Articles/252125/) of Ulrich Drepper's article series "What every programmer should know about memory" is a great read (as is the rest of the series).